# Redefining \bf, \it, \rm, \sl, \tt

Tags: fonts, typefaces

The following code compiles to a document that has the word "проба" only in roman typeface (first paragraph). How can I have this word in the other paragraphs, as well?

```
% Compile with luatex
\input{luaotfload.sty}
\font\f=FreeSerif\f
test проба
\par
\sl test проба
\par
\it test проба
\par
\bf test проба
\bye
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Plain TeX there is no font selection scheme. The meaning of `\bf` is

```
\fam\bffam \tenbf
```

where the first two tokens are meaningful in math mode, while `\tenbf` means

```
select font cmbx10
```

Unless you redefine the meaning of `\tenbf`, you'll continue to select the `cmbx10` font, which of course doesn't have Cyrillic characters.

```
% Compile with luatex
\input{luaotfload.sty}
\font\tenrm=FreeSerif
\font\tenbf=FreeSerifBold
\font\tenit=FreeSerifItalic
\rm % choose the upright font

test проба

%\sl test проба

\it test проба

\bf test проба

\bye
```

[image]

Note that FreeSerif doesn't have a slanted variant, but it can be faked:

```
% Compile with luatex
\input{luaotfload.sty}
\font\tenrm=FreeSerif
\font\tenbf=FreeSerifBold
\font\tenit=FreeSerifItalic
\font\tensl=FreeSerif:+slant=0.2

\rm % choose the upright font

test проба

\sl test проба

\it test проба

\bf test проба

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: FreeSerif doesn't have a typewriter variant either, right?

Comment: @AngelTsankov There is FreeMono, so you can do `\font\tentt=FreeMono`; for the sans serif family, there are FreeSans, FreeSansBold and FreeSansOblique.

Comment: FreeSerif has a BoldItalic typeface but \bl and \it cancel each other by default. Does this mean that I have to redefine them appropriately (or define a new macro, say \bi) in order to use the BoldItalic typeface?

Comment: @AngelTsankov Yes, unless you set up a (primitive) font selection scheme.